# Regex to catch all the words and the "i'm you're etc" in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to split lines of a document, by creating a `Pattern` in Java.
The default `Pattern` in WordCount example is something like this: `"\\s*\\b\\s*"`.
The problem with this pattern however, is that it splits everything to a single word, while I want to keep things such as (I'm, You're, it's) together. So far, what I've tried is `[a-zA-Z]+'{0,1}[a-zA-Z]*`,

the problem is that when I have a test string, for example:

```
Pattern BOUNDARY = "[a-zA-Z]+'{0,1}[a-zA-Z]*"
String test = "Hello i'm @£$@you @@can !!be.
```

and run

```
for(String word : BOUNDARY.split(test){
    println(word)}
```

I get no results. Ideally, I want to get

```
Hello
i'm
you
can
be
```

Any ideas are welcome. In the regex101.com the regex I've put up works like a charm, so I'm guessing I have misunderstood something in the Java part.

Comment: It is a *matching* regex, use `Matcher.find()` to get all non-overlapping occurrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial pattern was splitting at a word boundary enclosed with 0+ whitespaces pattern. The second pattern is *matching* substrings.

Use it like this:

```
String BOUNDARY_STR = "[a-zA-Z]+(?:'[a-zA-Z]+)?";
String test = "Hello i'm @£$@you @@can !!be.";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(BOUNDARY_STR).matcher(test);
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()){
    results.add(matcher.group(0));
} 
System.out.println(results); // => [Hello, i'm, you, can, be]
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/cgPB6p)

Note I used `[a-zA-Z]+(?:'[a-zA-Z]+)?` that matches

- `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters
- `(?:'[a-zA-Z]+)?` - an optional substring of

  - `'` - an apostrophe
  - `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters

You may also wrap the pattern with word boundaries to only match words that are enclosed with non-word chars, `"\\b[a-zA-Z]+(?:'[a-zA-Z]+)?\\b"`.

To find all Unicode letters, use `"\\p{L}+(?:'\\p{L}+)?"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought I got something wrong in my mind, just wasn't sure how to fix it. Why do you use this syntax for the optional substring? Is it more optimal than my version?

Comment: If you use `a+'?a*` you will match `a'`. Besides, if there is no `'` in the string, the pattern will work as `a+a*` that makes little sense. My example involves less backtracking. If you need to match `a'`, just replace the last `+` with `*`.